# How to convert a date in specific timezone to utc

Tags: javascript, timezone, date-formatting, timezone-offset

I am having a date string '2021-09-27 07:43' I also have the info that the date is in (GMT-8:00) Alaska time zone. I am in a different local timezone. When i convert this date to UTC , it is taking my timezone as the reference timezone.

```
const str = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Etc/GMT' });
```

How to do it with respect to a specific time zone as the reference rather than my local time?

Comment: `new Date('2021-09-27 07:43 GMT-8')` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
let myDate = "2021-09-27 07:43";
let myDateUTC = new Date(myDate + " UTC-8"); // 2021-09-27T15:43:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it using moment.js.
see Example:

```js
var input = '2021-09-27 07:43';
var fmt   = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm';  // must match the input
var zone  = 'Etc/GMT';

var m = moment.tz(input, fmt, zone);

m.utc();

var s = m.format(fmt)  // result:
console.log(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```